# Automatic clear of Text Form Field

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, textformfield

I have text form field to check full name of user , I want it to accept only
Arabic letters, English letters and space

this code work fine

```
  `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"^[\u0621-\u064Aa-zA-Z\d\-_\s]+$",))`,
```

but the problem when I enter any uncorrect char like `:`  or `;`

It clear Text form field directly

Answer (score 2):

remove `$` from the end of your RegExp

`FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"^[\u0621-\u064Aa-zA-Z\d\-_\s]+"))`